# make sails.js waterline case Sensitive

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

there is a way to configure waterline in sails to make query case sensitive ?
In this moment i can do onlycase-insensitive search  and these are too slow because index is not used

**[updated ]**
i try to use the following solution

```
  mysqlAdapter: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'tecreply',
    database: 'sailsApi',
    wlNext: {
      caseSensitive: true
    }
  }
```

but if i try to use the metod Find on my model i see that is still not case sensitive... someone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at : https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/239#issuecomment-216342636

Guys found solution for that.
You have to configure it in your connection settings, e.g.:

```
postgresql: {
  url: 'postgres://username:password@hostname:port/database',
  wlNext: {
    caseSensitive: true
  }
}
```

Comment: as I found it should work with MySQL,PostgreSQL and MongoDB at least.

Comment: Hi , i've tried to define my connection in this way   mysqlAdapter: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'tecreply',
    database: 'sailsApi',
    wlNext: {
      caseSensitive: true
    }
  } but it not worked .. the query is not case sensitive ..

Comment: it is working for others.. I think you should post it in that GH thread

Comment: Guys what option do we have to make queries case-insensitive with current latest Sails v1.2.4?